# Why Joel Greenblatt's Magic Formula ignores taxes and interest payments?

Tags: value-investing

The "Magic Formula" works by choosing companies scored the best in two criteria:

- How good business is, how efficiently it can reinvest its own money and grow `Return on Capital = EBIT / (Net Working Capital + Net Fixed Assets)`.
- How cheap we can buy it `EBIT / Enterprise Value`, EV calculated as a sum of Market Cap + all the debts.

So basically it looks - how fast business will be growing and how cheap we can buy it. Greenblatt says it removes the interest and taxes to **remove distortions** and compare companies working in different tax jurisdictions on the same ground.

What I don't understand why it ignores the taxes? For example we have two equal businesses in high-tax and low-tax countries. And the formula will score it as equals.

Although they are not, with all other things the same, business in low-tax country is preferable as it would generate more money after the taxes.

Comment: With regards to taxes, the distortion is due to non-uniformity.  For instance, the company might have a large write-off or tax bill one year.  This could change what is a profitable year into a loss on paper.  I'm not sure that is long enough to turn into an answer,though.

Comment: @Michael thanks, I see, makes sense. I initially had international markets in mind and was confused why he decided to ignore that.